# Как в питоне реализуется инверсия зависимостей?

Tags: python, solid

Обычно в качестве объяснения говорят, что надо реализовывать абстрактные классы - от них наследоваться, а в самом объекте принимать те типы, которые реализуют этот интерфейс, что-то вроде такого:

```
# Абстрактный класс для работы с базой данных
class Database(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass
    
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, query):
        pass


# Класс, который зависит от абстракции (Database)
class UserManager:
    def __init__(self, database: Database):
        self.db = database
        
    def get_users(self):
        query = "SELECT * FROM users"
        return self.db.execute(query)
```

Но ведь в Python типизация только на уровне соглашения, поэтому нам ничего не помешает передать в качестве аргумента `database` в `UserManager` то, что не реализует интерфейс `Database`, тогда в чем состоит зависимость?

Comment: *Но ведь в Python нет динамической типизации*. `Python` - это язык, в котором как раз только такая типизация и есть

Comment: @n1tr0xs да, я неправильно написал, хотел сказать, что типизация только на уровне соглашения

Comment: «нам ничего не помешает...» — совесть помешает  Ну а технически ничего не помешает, потому что типизация динамическая и утиная

Comment: @andreymal то есть можно сказать, что в питоне инверсию зависимостей в явном виде реализовать не получится?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает показанный в вашем коде вариант? Соглашение есть, при его нарушении линтеры кода будут ругаться - что ещё нужно для счастья?)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо!